# Why do I get ECONNREFUSED|ECONNREFUSED for an openvpn server, after doing easyrsa gen-crl?

Tags: openvpn, certificate, arch-linux

My OpenVPN server has been working perfectly fine on an Arch Linux install. I've done regular pacman -Syu updates over the past year, every now and then I've had to run:

```
easyrsa gen-crl
```

When the certificate for the only client using the server expires. I could probably have fixed this in a better way, I just never got around to it, and I'm the only one using it anyway.

It expired again, and this time I ran gen-crl like before, but now all I get is:

```
openvpn[484]: read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED|ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (fd=7,code=111)
```

I get this every time the client attempts to connect. Note that before when I ran gen-crl, I didn't need to do anything on the client. I could just use openvpn against the same .conf file as before.

I know for a fact that there is nothing from with the port being closed or that the IP is wrong. Not only can I confirm that there is a connection from seeing the "Connection refused" message show up in the log for the VPN server, but I can also just listen with netcat on the same port on the server (after stopping the VPN server) and see that indeed, the client attempts to connect and initiate the handshake.

I'm just not experienced enough to that easily figure out what the problem is here. I've never had to do anything beyond running:

easyrsa gen-crl

I have ensured that the file permissions are correct for the generated crl.pem file (this has been an issue before), that's not the issue, when that was the issue, the openvpn service failed to start.

I have remembered to do systemctl restart for the openvpn service.

I have tried to reboot.

I have tried to do a pacman -Syu update on the server.

I've also tried to regenerate the client certificate.

Comment: Is the VPN server running at all? What does `systemctl status openvpn` say? What is in the logs of the server?

Comment: @Lacek Yes, it is definitely running, I can see connections coming in from the client when I run journalctl -xeu openvpn-server@server.service

I've also tried running it in the foreground (by executing openvpn-server manually), I can again see connections coming in and failing as described in the initial post.